# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable(Amazon review scraping)

Tags: web-scraping, typeerror

I was trying to scrap the amazon product reviews
This is the code

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

class Reviews:
    def __init__(self, asin) -> None:
        self.asin = asin
        self.session = HTMLSession()
        self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
        self.url = f'https://www.amazon.in/product-reviews/{self.asin}/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber='
    
    def pageination(self,page):
        r = self.session.get(self.url + str(page))
        if not r.html.find('div[data-hook=review]'):
            return False
        else:
            return r.html.find('div[data-hook=review]')
    
    def parse(self, reviews):
        total = []
        for review in reviews:
            title = review.find('a[data-hook=review-title]', first = True).text
            rating = review.find('i[data-hook=review-star-rating] span', first=True).text
            body = review.find('span[data-hook=review-body] span', first=True).text.replace('\n','').strip()
            
            data = {
                'title': title,
                'rating': rating,
                'body': body[:100]
            }
            total.append(data)
        return total
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    amz = Reviews('B08L5TGWD1')
    reviews = amz.pageination(3)
    print(amz.parse(reviews))
```

It is working for first page but not for any other pages
the notebook is showing error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <module>
      2 amz = Reviews('B08L5QS9BJ')
      3 reviews = amz.pageination(2)
----> 4 print(amz.parse(reviews))

Input In [17], in Reviews.parse(self, reviews)
     22 def parse(self, reviews):
     23     total = []
---> 24     for review in reviews:
     25         title = review.find('a[data-hook=review-title]', first = True).text
     26         rating = review.find('i[data-hook=review-star-rating] span', first=True).text

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

I tried finding solution and add few things to the header but it didn't work